# How generally to refer to a function's argument in the course of further coding?

Tags: r, function, reference, arguments, naming

How can I refer to the choice of a function's argument in the course of my further coding?---A specific example:

```
library("quantmod")

INDEX<-get(getSymbols("^GDAXI", from="2006-01-01"))
INDEX.SMA<-SMA(INDEX[,4],n=360)

INDEX<-INDEX[,4]
colnames(INDEX)<-c("Close")
colnames(INDEX.SMA)<-"360"
```

The function SMA(INDEX,n=360) generates the moving average of closing prices in INDEX.

I would like to have the chosen argument of 360 be automatically reflected in colnames(INDEX.SMA). Thus, I don't want to change it manually to, say, "200", four lines further down after changing my code to

```
INDEX.SMA<-SMA(INDEX[,4],n=200)
```

Replacing

```
colnames(INDEX.SMA)<-"360"
```

with

```
colnames(INDEX.SMA)<-as.character(length(INDEX.SMA)-sum(!is.na(INDEX.SMA))+1)
```

did the job in this specific example. Is there a more general solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use a value in multiple places, you should make it a variable

```
library("quantmod")

mytime<-360

INDEX<-get(getSymbols("^GDAXI", from="2006-01-01"))
INDEX.SMA<-SMA(INDEX[,4],n=mytime)

INDEX<-INDEX[,4]
colnames(INDEX)<-c("Close")
colnames(INDEX.SMA)<-as.character(mytime)
```